# Why is this JavaScript not working on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

In summary, I'm trying to hide the text next to an image when the web page loads and then display the text when the user hovers over the corresponding image.

I can't seem to get it to display the text. Here's the code:

```
<section class = muliticolumn >
        <img class="menuSmall" src="../images/margherita.png" onmouseover="showMargTopp()">
        <h2>Margherita</h2>
        <p id="margTopp">Tomato, mozzarella and basil</p>
    </section>
```

This is the code for the image and text.

```
#margTopp{display:none;}
```

CSS.

```
function showMargTopp() {
        document.getElementByID("margTopp").style.display="block";
    }
```

JavaScript.

I've tried a couple different things but I can't seem to get it to work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: `getElementByID` => `getElementById`, JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Just FWIW, you don't need JavaScript for this at all, CSS can do it with a [subsequent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators): `.menuSmall:hover ~ #margTopp { display: block; }`. That also has the advantage of making it disappear again when the mouse leaves the image. - https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/r1k79ujy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID should be Id in your function.

```
function showMargTopp() {
  document.getElementById("margTopp").style.display="block";
}
```

If you want it to be hidden again when you stop hovering, you will need another function for the `onmouseout` event.

```
function hideMargTopp() {
  document.getElementById("margTopp").style.display="none";
}
```

A simpler solution to this would be to use CSS `:hover`